# How can I add a subdivision surface modifier to smooth the rounding of an object?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I have a simple object with two rounded corners. The following screenshot shows the magnification of one of these corners. The corners were created with the bevel function.

[image: Screenshot Magnification]

Adding a subdivision surface modifier destroys the whole object.

Should I use more bevel segments from the beginning?

The object can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/t/JjbxccUV4YgI6zrG

Comment: If you want the surfaces to look smooth, right click > Shade Smooth, then play with the Auto Smooth angle value (10° works fine). If you want the edges to be smoother I guess you need to add Subdivision Surface but you'll need to change the topology (or sharp the edges with some modifiers or other tricks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christopher's answer did not work for me, even if I added supporting edge loops on both sides of the groove. But adding a "Weighted Normal" modifier to the stack finally did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using supporting geometry. In the case of your object, adding edge loops at the places I've highlighted will give a clean look with a subdivision surface. Be careful positioning the large rectangle loop, because It seemed to cause artifacts in the bottom left area if not placed just right.

[image: LoopCuts]

Hope this helps.